# Scanning Strings on Multiple input lines - C language

Tags: c, string

I've got the following input:

```
10/9/02 9:15:59 23.845089 38.018470 DXUYHu

10/9/02 9:16:29 23.845179 38.018069 tKoPTx

10/9/02 9:16:59 23.845530 38.018241 JPQbNb

10/9/02 9:17:29 23.845499 38.017440 aEWdXS

10/9/02 9:17:59 23.844780 38.015609 gqeEjx

10/9/02 9:18:29 23.844780 38.014018 aQArkX

10/9/02 9:18:59 23.844869 38.012569 fhQIAS

10/9/02 9:19:29 23.845360 38.011600 BhngfQ

10/9/02 9:19:59 23.845550 38.010650 rgwehm

10/9/02 9:20:29 23.845100 38.010478 jdBgpN
```

and I am trying to develop a code which reads the final 6 character - the string for each line and thus prints it out. For some reason the code I've developed only prints out the final string 'jdBgpN' please help as to why.

```
for (i = 0; i <= LASTROW-1; i++ ) {
    scanf("%d/%d/%d %d:%d:%d %lf %lf %s",&day, &month, &year, 
           &hour, &minute, &second, &longi, &lati, id);`
}

for (i=0; i < LASTROW; i++) {
    scanf("%s", id[i]);
}

for (i=0; i < LASTROW; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", id[i]);
}
```

Comment: How and where is `id` defined? Would be good to have a compilable example.

Comment: The `%s` format spec for `scanf` can't be right for both `id` and `id[i]`. One common reason for your problem is that there is only one buffer, so the previous codes get overwritten.

Comment: It is unclear what the code is doing. In the first snippet it looks as though you are overwriting say `char id[1000]` in each loop. In the follow pair of loops it must be a different `id`, perhaps `char *id[LASTROW]`, and how is the first part of each input skipped? Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: I would personally create a struct that holds each of the elements and save every struct as a node in a list.

Comment: `id` seems to be a character pointer, since you used it with `%s` in the first `scanf()` but then you used `id[i]` as another char pointer in the second `scanf()`. Does this code even compile?

Answer (score 1):

In the first for loop you overwrite your id, so you only keep one value

```
for (i = 0; i <= LASTROW-1; i++ ) {
    scanf("%d/%d/%d %d:%d:%d %lf %lf %s",&day, &month, &year, 
           &hour, &minute, &second, &longi, &lati, id);`
}
```

Assuming that id is an array, then the array variable can be treated as a pointer and you can add the index to the variable to move along the arrray.

```
for (i = 0; i <= LASTROW-1; i++ ) {
    scanf("%d/%d/%d %d:%d:%d %lf %lf %s",&day, &month, &year, 
           &hour, &minute, &second, &longi, &lati, id + i);`
}
```